# Different types of runtime exception handling

Tags: java, exception

I have a piece of code, which can throw 3 types of exception which all extended Runtime exception.

So, if I catch all these 3 exception separately in different catch, so would it go to different catch according to the exception occurred.

I am just doubtful because all 3 are RuntimeExceptions, so can it come to just 1st catch since that's also a run time exception but its not the same exception as was thrown.

Comment: So what is your question now ?

Comment: Cool..do you have any question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No. Your `catch` block will catch what it is supposed to catch. You tell it to catch a `AwesomeRuntimeException`, it will catch those. It won't go out of it's way to catch a `DistastefulRuntimeException`, just because both extend the same class.

It's just like you can't create an array of `Car` objects and then put `Bike` objects into it, just because both extend `Vehicle`.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is rather simple:

- when you want/can do **different** processing for an exception, then it needs its distinct catch block
- when you only do something generic (like logging the exception), then a single catch block does the job.

In other words: this fully depends on your requirements. You need distinct catch blocks for cases when you need distinct exception handling.

So the point is, you would *either* have this:

```
try {
  ...
} catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
  ...
} catch (NullPointerException ne) {
  ...
...
```

**or**

```
try {
  ...
} catch (RuntimeException r) {
  ...
}
...
```

(where catching something like NPE really isn't recommended; I just used that as example for some  RuntimeException)